# SQL to query greater than today's date and time, with time defaulting to 12:00:00 AM

Tags: sql, date, time, getdate

Format of the time/date in the table from which I am querying is the following: `11/12/2015  12:00:00 AM`. 
I would like to be able to query if the date is greater than or equal today, but look for results as the above format. Using `getdate()` returns the current specific time. Also, the specific format includes two spaces between the date and time.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: And what have you tried? What database are you using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i am using oracle. this is what i have so far. apologies for the lack on information, i just started using sql today. i search around on the internet, but to no aval.

SELECT * from trd
where dt_expctd_setmt = '11/12/2015  12:00:00 AM'

'11/12/2015  12:00:00 AM' needs to update dynamically based on today's date, with the time starting at 12am.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the time from consideration as follows:

```
WHERE CAST(YourDateTime AS DATE) >= CAST(getdate() AS DATE)
```